# Facing error while installing Apache2 in Ubuntu 14.04 'has no installation candidate'

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-14.04, lamp

I don't know what I did but I'm not able to install apache2 in my Ubuntu 14.04.

When I use `sudo apt-get install apache2` I face this error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package apache2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
libapache2-mpm-itk:i386 libapache2-mpm-itk

E: Package 'apache2' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 4):

First make sure that your proxy is disabled as that can cause a problem sometimes.
Then run the following.

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install apache2`

If that doesn't work you can always compile your own apache2. A tutorial for that is located here: https://www.virgohacks.net/install-apache-2-4-mysql-5-6-php-5-5-source-ubuntu-14-04/

Good luck